# Bash file: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripting, here-document

I have the following script

```
ssh user@host << EOF

    STATUS="$(git status)"
    SEARCH_STATUS="Not a git"

    if [[ "$STATUS" == *$SEARCH_STATUS* ]]; then
        echo "Not a git repository"
    fi

EOF
```

I am getting the following error

```
-bash: line 3: file: No such file or directory
```

Which corresponds to this line

```
STATUS="$(git status)"
```

The issue here is, is that the above line is working, git does exist, and is executing as planned, and storing the output of the git command in STATUS, and the If statement is executing as planned as well, which echo's when the status of git matches the "Not a git" string...

what I don't understand is, is why it's throwing that error, any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the questions you marked it a duplicate of... I am not asking, how to pass and set variables, or how to force a remote command, I am asking, why am I getting No such file or directory on a specific line

Comment: The cause is the same. The contents of the here-document is evaluated locally. The solution is the same. Quote the here-document (or the parts of it that shouldn't be evaluated).

Answer (score 1):

The shell is expanding the commands on your machine not the remote one.

Quote 'EOF'

```
ssh user@host<<'EOF'
STATUS="$(git status)"
EOF
```

From `man bash`:

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
>   trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are
>   then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,
>   or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word
>   are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and
>   the lines in  the  here-document are not expanded.  **If word is
>   unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion**.  In the
>   latter case, the character sequence \ is ignored,  and  \ 
>   must  be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

**Edit**

Your test is also wrong. You could use `grep` to check if the required string is in the output:

```
ssh user@host <<'EOF'
if git status 2>&1 | grep -q 'Not a git' ; then
  echo 'Not a git repository'
fi
EOF
```

or if you want to retain the status in a variable

```
ssh user@host <<'EOF'
STATUS=$(git status 2>&1)
if echo $STATUS | grep -q 'Not a git' ; then
  echo 'Not a git repository'
fi
EOF
```

Note that you will have to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` with `2>&1`

**Edit 2**

If you force `bash` you can also

```
ssh user@host bash <<'EOF'
STATUS=$(git status 2>&1)
SEARCH_STATUS="ot a git"
echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
if [[ "$STATUS" == *$SEARCH_STATUS* ]]; then
  echo 'Not a git repository'
fi
EOF
```

Beware that on macOS and Linux I got different capitalisations of 'Not'/'not'. Therefore the `SEARCH_STATUS` is just `ot a git` and not `Not a git`

Comment: I quoted EOF, however, now the script does not work as planned... it does not echo "Not a git repository" ...

Comment: There are also problems with your test `*` is expanded by the shell with the list of files in the current directory. It cannot be used for string comparisons.

Comment: @Matteo Actually, in Bash, the `*` within `[[ ... ]]` is not used for [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) but for [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). Try `[[ foo == f* ]] && echo true`, it prints `true`. OTOH, `*` within `[ ... ]` does trigger filename expansion because `[` is a command (usually built in the shell), not a reserved word like `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: @nxnev You are right I didn't notice the `[[`, but there is no guarantee that bash will be the shell used on the other side

Comment: @Matteo Yeah, fair point.